# Failed to authenticate centos - trying password auth in chef knife instance creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

when i try to launch and instance from my chef workstation i am getting this error

```
"Connecting to xx.212.xxx.xxx
Failed to authenticate centos - trying password auth".
```

but the instance has been creating, but it is not listing in chef server. can somebody help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bootstrap the node. Then it will be visible in the chef server node section.